# The iPhone function selectRowAtIndexPath doesn't work on UITableView when the item is offscreen

Tags: iphone, uitableview

It works fine when the cell to select is visible in the scroll area. If it's not in the currently visible scroll area, then it has never been loaded via cellForRowAtIndexPath, and it doesn't get selected. And isn't scrolled to. What's up with that?

This is on the iPhone 3.1.2 Simulator.

Thanks,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

oh right i got it, it's because that function wasn't being called so i wasn't setting the selected index. facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing the same problem and can't figure out what this guy says, here is my interpretation:

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called only for visible items, thus the offscreen items aren't properly initialised when you want to select them in `viewDidLoad` via `selectRowAtIndexPath`.

I hacked it this way:

```
[ self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self indexPathForSelectedItem] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO ];
double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){       
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[self indexPathForSelectedItem] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
});
```

I needed the 0.1s delay to wait for items to get initialised.. I know it's not the prettiest solution, but it works.
If anyone has a better idea, I'd be happy to get rid of this `dirty hack`.

Cheers.